# What are the SSL options to connect my new users to my PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, users, azure-postgres-database

I want to create a new user in my database PostreSQL database hosted on Azure.

So, following [the documentation from Microsoft for pgAdmin,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-create-users) I went to PGAdmin and ran the following command:

```
CREATE ROLE rikkiWITH LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE NOREPLICATION PASSWORD 'Fete321@';

GRANT azure_pg_admin TO rikki;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It worked well. Yet, when trying to create a new server with this new login I had some issues

[image]

- I disabled SSL connection, so I don't have this error anymore
- For the password error, I just copied and paste the password I just created but it gives back this error.

So can I create new users that would be able to connect remotely to my PostgreSQL database?

I tried to connect myself through command line and got

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin>psql --host=######.postgres.database.azure.com --port=5432 --username=rikki@######--dbname=capi
Password for user rikki@######:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "rikki"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "rikki"
```

Comment: Why do you think the MySQL documentation is relevant for PostgreSQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, I didn't realize. I apologize

Comment: you adjusted the first query for postgres - the other 2 lines are right in the manual page that Phil gave you

Comment: @eagle275 Yes. Despite of this I can't connect to the server because of SSL options which they don't talk about in the link. For the password error, I just copied and paste the password I just created but it gives back this error

Answer (score 2):

Read the title of the documentation link you have given. "Create users in Azure Database for **MySQL** server". You're using MySQL syntax to try and create a user in Postgres.

You'll be wanting to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-create-users).

Comment: Thank you, my bad. I apologize. I am not very good in database administration. I updated my question.  I can't connect to the server because of SSL options which they don't talk about in the link. For the password error, I just copied and paste the password I just created but it gives back this error

Answer (score 0):

adding up on my comment:

you created a new user in server #1 - This user doesn't exist when creating a server #2
Why do you think you need another server - usually you want a new database-instance in server #1 for your new user

```
CREATE DATABASE <newdb>;

CREATE ROLE <db_user> WITH LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION PASSWORD '<StrongPassword!>';

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE <newdb> TO <db_user>;
```

from Phil's linked manual page

if you want the new user with advanced privileges

> Using an admin account, you may need to grant additional privileges to secure the objects in the database. Refer to the PostgreSQL documentation for further details on database roles and privileges. For example:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <newdb> TO <db_user>;
```

Comment: I thought I needed [to create another server instance](https://pasteboard.co/IHR3EfP.png) because as far as when I connect to my first server in pgAdmin I have to add the admin credentials I thought one had to create another server instance in pgAdmin. Whatever the user I just want to test if I'm able to connect to my database being another user

Comment: to connect use and adjust Azure-CLI >psql --host=mydemoserver.postgres.database.azure.com --port=5432 --username=db_user@mydemoserver --dbname=newdb

Comment: Ah, there is now way to do it through pgAdmin?

Comment: should work the same way ... I suggest you dig through the page Phil linked - and some more of the azure documentation by microsoft

Comment: Yes, I read it all and now watching [this video, _Connect; 2017 Overview Azure Database for PostgreSQL and MySQL
_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_5quWLFMBw). Yet I don't get why I can't connect with this new user providing the password I provided in the command line in the doc